# Error with #!/BIN/BASH MAC

Tags: command-line, server, bash

I am trying to host a unturned server, and I watched a tutorial on youtube.

So that is what I wrote in textedit for the launcher of the server (a .command) :

```
#!/BIN/BASH
/Users/username/Desktop/Unturned/Unturned.app/Contents/MacOS/Unturned -nogui -batchmode +secureserver/ServeurQC
```

btw, I called the file (Unturned Serveur.command) without the ()

but it is giving me this error :

```
-bash: /Users/username/Desktop/Unturned Serveur.command: /BIN/BASH^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

logout

can someone help me.

Comment: This does not look like a command.

Comment: I voted to close this question since this site is about Ubuntu, and your question is about Mac OS. You can ask Mac OS questions on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) or on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). However, to quickly address your issue, Unix systems are case-sensitive, hence the path to `bash` is so also: `#!/bin/bash [...]`.

Comment: Plus what heemayl stated in its answer, you are probably using an old (non-OSX) Mac OS-style line break, which uses carriage returns in place of line feeds.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting the error :

```
/BIN/BASH^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

because there is no file named `/BIN/BASH` in Linux systems (unless you create one yourself). All Linux systems are case-sensitive, so `#!/bin/bash` and `#!/BIN/BASH` are totally different.

To solve the interpreter related issue, make the shebang as :

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Or prefarably :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Also you seems to have carriage return as your line terminator, but Linux systems use line feed to terminate lines. So you should correct it yourself or use a simple program line `dos2unix` to do the job.

You can simply do the conversion by :

```
dos2unix filename
```

It is not installed by default, you can install it by :

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

Comment: I do not think this is the only problem. There is also <CR> symbol there.

Comment: Unix systems, you probably didn't notice but OP is using Mac OS ;)

Comment: @Pilot6 fixed..

Comment: @kos my bad..i did not notice the `BIG MAC`  :D

Comment: I am not on linux

Comment: @TheKiller Then please ask this question on http://apple.stackexchange.com/  ..they are pro in MAC related issues..

Comment: @TheKiller BTW i have pointed out the basic issues..you can build upon these..